# how to mock a class which an extension of other class in Angular Jasmine

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Let's say I have a class like below,

```
Class MyClass{

   protected id: number;
   protected name: string;
   protected x:...
   protected y:...

   // it has many properties, assume 100 other properties


   setId(id:string){
        this.id = id;
   }

   getId(){
        return this.id;
   }


   // get/set is applicable to all properties

}
```

Then,

I have some class

```
class SomeClass extends MyClass{

     dimension: number;

     // assume it has its own definition and implementation
}
```

Somewhere in .ts file, I'm using a function like

```
calculation(myClassObject: SomeClass){
  ...
  ...
  
}
```

I want to unit test `calculation` function So I obviously want to mock SomeClass but I don't mock it rather I use that class itself directly.

```
let someClass:SomeClass = new SomeClass();

     someClass.dimension = 12;
```

somewhere in my .spec.ts file,

```
     component.calculation(someClass); // someClass is not compitable.
```

Since SomeClass extends MyClass which further has 100 fields, it throws error like properties are missing. I do understand why but the problem is I can' define all those 100 fields. Is there any simplest way to deal with it.

OR

How can I mock `SomeClass` ?

Comment: you can directly override some methods, so their behavior would be mocked, and wouldn't throw error. `jasmine.spyOn(someClass, 'someMethod').and.callFake(() => 123)`

Answer (score 1):

[MockService](https://ng-mocks.sudo.eu/api/MockService) from [ng-mocks](https://github.com/ike18t/ng-mocks) could be used for that:

```js
const someClass = MockService(SomeClass, {
  dimension: 12,
});
// someClass is an instance of SomeClass
// but all its methods are dummy functions.
component.calculation(someClass);
```